I want to replace the current 3 yr old Honeywell thermostat,with a newer Honeywell model with remote sensor. Is this a DIY?
I want to replace the current 3 yr old Honeywell thermostat, with a newer Honeywell  model with remote sensor. Is this a DIY?

It would help if you add to the question, the model number of the old and new thermostats.  Also helpful, a clear photo of the wires behind the old thermostat including any loose wires that are not connected to it. Also helpful, links to manuals for both thermostats.  There is no way to answer the question as is.

If you don't even know how to remove the old thermostat from the wall to take a picture, learning that would be an excellent and easy way into DIY. Post a new question, asking just that, with a photo of the thermostat on the wall and the model number.

Is this a DIY? ... entirely dependent on your skill

I’ll get the info tomorrow from the existing thermostat. I believe the Honeywell WiFi Vision-Pro 8000 will be the replacement.

Replacing a thermostat is generally a pretty straightforward task, but it's difficult for people to judge what you are comfortable with doing. If you're planning on using a wireless sensor, this should be a pretty easy job. Just make sure that you turn off the breaker to HVAC system before you get started and take a photo of the connections to your current thermostat. Before you remove the old thermostat, make sure you know which wires are which and how they need to be connected on your new thermostat.
